# Use Count function inside conditional part of Case Expression

Tags: sql, oracle, count, aggregate-functions, case-when

I have two tables with the following sample records in oracle database

**1. staffs**

```
inst_name   name    sid
ABC         John    1
PQR         Sam     2
ABC         Tom     3
ABC         Amit    4
PQR         Jack    5
```

**2. staffaccounts**

```
sid     account_no
1       4587
1       4588
2       4589
3       4581
3       4582
5       4583
5       4585
4       4586
```

Where I want the result like

```
inst_name   account_type    total
PQR         SINGLE          1
ABC         SINGLE          1
PQR         DOUBLE          1
ABC         DOUBLE          2
```

This can be achieved by a outer query, but I want to write a query where there is no outer query. Want to accomplish it in one single query.

```
SELECT
    A .inst_name,
    (
        CASE COUNT (b.ac_no)
        WHEN 1 THEN
            'Single'
        WHEN 2 THEN
            'Double'
        END
    ) account_type,
    COUNT (A . NAME)
FROM
    staffs A,
    staffaccounts b
WHERE
    A . s_id = b.s_id
GROUP BY
    A .inst_name
```

The above query gives error `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`. Can it be done in single query or is outer query the only way out.

```
Oracle Version is 10g
```

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement. (It returns a value.)

Comment: For `PQR` how come total is 1. It should be 2. Isn't it ?

Comment: @XING `PQR` has only one staff `Sam` with Single account in `staffaccounts` table. So `PQR` has 1 in Single Account type and 1 in Double Account type

Comment: I think one more `ABC` should be listed in the expected result as `Double Double Single`.

Comment: @Susang no as `PQR` has 1 staff each with single account and one with double and `ABC` has two staffs with double account and 1 with single account. In total 5 staffs `(1(PQR-S)+1(ABC-S)+1(PQR-D)+2(ABC-D)) `.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this would work.

```
SELECT
    A.inst_name,
        CASE COUNT (b.account_no)
        WHEN 1 THEN
            'Single'
        WHEN 2 THEN
            'Double'
        END account_type,
    COUNT (A.name)
FROM
    staffs A JOIN
    staffaccounts b
ON
    A.SID = b.sid
GROUP BY
    A.inst_name , a.sid
    ORDER BY 3;
```

Comment: @SangeetMenon : Could you explain how  this line `PQR         DOUBLE          1` should come in your result?. Otherwise, the query seems to work fine.

Comment: In `staffs` table `PQR         Jack    5`  and Jack has 2 accounts in `staffaccounts` so thats why `PQR DOUBLE 1`

Answer (score 0):

You should learn how to properly use `JOIN` syntax.  I prefer the explicit comparison syntax for `CASE`.

This may be what you want:

```
SELECT s.inst_name,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(sa.ac_no) = 1 THEN 'Single'
             WHEN COUNT(sa.ac_no) = 2 THEN 'Double'
        END) as account_type,
       COUNT(*)
FROM staffs s JOIN
     staffaccounts sa
     ON s.SID = sa.sid
GROUP BY s.inst_name;
```

EDIT:

Now I see what you want:

```
SELECT s.inst_name,
       (CASE WHEN cnt = 1 THEN 'Single'
             WHEN cnt = 2 THEN 'Double'
        END) as account_type,
       COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT s.*, COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM staffs s JOIN
           staffaccounts sa
           ON s.SID = sa.sid
      GROUP BY s.id
     ) s
GROUP BY s.inst_name,
         (CASE WHEN cnt = 1 THEN 'Single'
               WHEN cnt = 2 THEN 'Double'
          END);
```

Comment: Changing the Join does not give the desired result. Thanks. Your query returns the same result as mine.

Comment: @SangeetMenon . . . See the edit to the answer.  I didn't understand what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by `inst_name`, but this is not what you actually want, because you don't want a result row per `inst_name`, but per `inst_name` and `account_type`.

```
select
  s.inst_name,
  sa.account_type,
  count(*) as total
from staffs s
join
(
  select 
    sid, 
    case when count(*) = 1 then 'SINGLE' else 'DOUBLE' end as account_type
  from staffaccounts
  group by sid
  having count(*) <= 2
) sa on sa.sid = s.sid
group by sa.account_type, s.inst_name
order by sa.account_type, s.inst_name;
```

Comment: As I said.. I don't want a outer query. you have two queries(inner and outer) and I want to avoid that. Thanks

Comment: Ah okay, you don't want to select from a derived table. Still, you want an aggregation over an aggregation. I guess you can trick your way through with `COUNT OVER` plus `DISTINCT`, but that would only lead to an obfuscated and slower query. So why would you want to do this? Why write a worse query only to obey some queer rules?

Comment: I am stuck with the rules for now. Can give me a query on how you actually can do it with `COUNT OVER` plus `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 0):

**I got** only the way by using `subquery` but is in the easy way `(more easier and readable)` to achieve your requirement

```
SELECT inst_name, account_type, count(total) as total
FROM (
    SELECT
        a.inst_name, 
        CASE 
            WHEN COUNT (b.account_no) = 1 THEN 'Single'
            WHEN COUNT (b.account_no) = 2 THEN 'Double'
        END AS account_type,
        COUNT (a.name) AS total
    FROM staffs a
    INNER JOIN staffaccounts b ON A . SID = b.sid
    GROUP BY a.inst_name, a.sid) t GROUP BY inst_name, account_type
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
inst_name   account_type    total
ABC         Double          2
PQR         Double          1
ABC         Single          1
PQR         Single          1
```

Comment: I know that a `sub-query` the best solution but unfortunately I can't work with that. Thanks